# convert a numpy array values to a list of string values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to convert a numpy array  values to list of string values .
example :

```
convert(array(['Country Name',2008.0, 2009.0]))
['Country Name','2008.0', '2009.0']
```

Comment: `array(['Country Name',2008.0, 2009.0]).tolist()` basically.

Comment: `array(['Country Name',2008.0, 2009.0]).tolist()`
=> `['Country Name',2008.0, 2009.0]`  I want to get  :  `['Country Name','2008.0', '2009.0']`

Comment: A simple extension: `array(['Country Name',2008.0, 2009.0]).astype(str).tolist()`

Comment: thank you . I was looking for this 'astype' function